# How can i decode a ü to %FC in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, decode, encode

i tried a long time to decode a ü to %FC but nothing helped. I hope someone can help me.

Here is a example url with this code:

```
http://www2.dasoertliche.de/?form_name=search_nat_ext&vert_ok=1&zvo_ok=1&kgs=09162000&rgid=&buab=&zbuab=&buc=2247&sst=yes&page=1&action=43&st=Drygalski-Allee+51&choose=true&sfn=yes&image=Finden&skw=yes&context=1&book=96&ci=M%FCnchen&noList=false
```

Best regards

Gimo

Comment: What do you really want to do this with url???

Comment: You mean that you want decode a `ü` _from_ `%FC`? You can't, at least in utf-8. In utf-8 the `ü` char can be url-encoded with two byte (`%C3%BC`), not one. You're just incoherent with the encoding somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Here You can encode your URL like this way :

```
<?php
// Here to encode whole URL
$url = "http://www2.dasoertliche.de/?form_name=search_nat_ext&vert_ok=1&zvo_ok=1&kgs=09162000&rgid=&buab=&zbuab=&buc=2247&sst=yes&page=1&action=43&st=Drygalski-Allee+51&choose=true&sfn=yes&image=Finden&skw=yes&context=1&book=96&ci=München&noList=false";
$encoded = urlencode($url);
echo "Encoded URL : ".$encoded."</br></br></br>";
$decoded = urldecode($encoded);
echo "Decoded URL : ".$decoded."</br></br></br>";

//Or If you want to just encode the certain required part so here you can do like this way
$url = "http://www2.dasoertliche.de/?form_name=search_nat_ext&vert_ok=1&zvo_ok=1&kgs=09162000&rgid=&buab=&zbuab=&buc=2247&sst=yes&page=1&action=43&st=Drygalski-Allee+51&choose=true&sfn=yes&image=Finden&skw=yes&context=1&book=96&ci=M".urlencode("ü")."nchen&noList=false";
echo "URL With Required Encoded Part : ".$url;
?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Encoded URL : http%3A%2F%2Fwww2.dasoertliche.de%2F%3Fform_name%3Dsearch_nat_ext%26vert_ok%3D1%26zvo_ok%3D1%26kgs%3D09162000%26rgid%3D%26buab%3D%26zbuab%3D%26buc%3D2247%26sst%3Dyes%26page%3D1%26action%3D43%26st%3DDrygalski-Allee%2B51%26choose%3Dtrue%26sfn%3Dyes%26image%3DFinden%26skw%3Dyes%26context%3D1%26book%3D96%26ci%3DM%C3%BCnchen%26noList%3Dfalse


Decoded URL : http://www2.dasoertliche.de/?form_name=search_nat_ext&vert_ok=1&zvo_ok=1&kgs=09162000&rgid=&buab=&zbuab=&buc=2247&sst=yes&page=1&action=43&st=Drygalski-Allee+51&choose=true&sfn=yes&image=Finden&skw=yes&context=1&book=96&ci=München&noList=false


URL With Required Encoded Part : http://www2.dasoertliche.de/?form_name=search_nat_ext&vert_ok=1&zvo_ok=1&kgs=09162000&rgid=&buab=&zbuab=&buc=2247&sst=yes&page=1&action=43&st=Drygalski-Allee+51&choose=true&sfn=yes&image=Finden&skw=yes&context=1&book=96&ci=M%C3%BCnchen&noList=false
```